Track downloads from cloud environment (O365) to physical device
We are currently in the process of blocking all storage USB drives from being able to download data from domain joined machines.
we suspect that users will then access our cloud environment, primarily SharePoint, from non domain joined machines to then download the information.
Currently we do not want to block this but what to monitor it.
We are currently looking at implementing session and access policies using Microsoft Entra ID.
Was wondering if there is another solution. We have a P1 license for Entra so this is no problem.
Also any hints on how to do this efficiently would be great.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
